# Как сделать фильтр относительно предыдущего поля в форме

Tags: python, django

Есть форма, в которой нужно сделать фильтр относительно предыдущего поля, если в предыдущем поле одно, то в следующем поле одни варианты, и так далее

```
модель формы
car_name = models.ForeignKey(Cars)
detail = models.ForeignKey(Details)

модель Details
details_cars = models.ForeignKey(Cars)
```

[image]

то есть относительно Car name изменяются варианты detail

Answer (score 1):

Это не в *Django* делается, а в *JS*. Если ВЫ конечно не захотите заставлять пользователя перезагружать страницу после каждого выбора `Car name`.

Я бы сделал так. В *Django* подготавливается *JSON* вида `[{car_name: ['коленвал', 'колесо'], car_name: ['колесо']}`, во вьюхе или после загрузки страницы подтягивается этот *JSON* ну и далее оперируете *JS*. Вешаются триггеры на `event` отслеживаются и обновляются селекты.